# Authentication failed while using git pull

Tags: git, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-repository

I am trying to clone Remote repository into Local repository from Google cloud repository. I am working on  Kubuntu 14.04 system

First i have create empty local git repository using

```
git init test
```

then i have tried with following command

```
cd test
git pull https://source.developers.google.com/p/{project_id}
Username for 'https://source.developers.google.com': #########
Password for 'https://########@source.developers.google.com':
```

But i get following error:

> fatal: Authentication failed for `https://source.developers.google.com/p/{project_id}/`

`Username` and `password` are correct i have tried to find solution on `SO` but it is about `GITHUB` not `Google cloud repository`.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The docs say you have to install a `credential.helper` for working with the repos: https://cloud.google.com/tools/cloud-repositories/docs/cloud-repositories-local-repository Did you do that?

Comment: @eckes I have followoed that link and try this command: 'git config credential.helper gcloud.sh' and it works after that. Thank you so much

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use this command to clone

```
git clone https://source.developers.google.com/p/{project_id}
```

You can also refer below link for more understanding 
: https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/git.html

Comment: you can try **git remote update ** : To fetch remote branches locally

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/10261023)

Comment: @bfontaine I disagree that this is a link-only answer. The "essential parts" are given here in the form of a command.

Comment: @Barett i agree with you.